# roscore does not work with diamondback on karmic

Tags: roscore, ubuntu, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros in ubuntu 9.10- the Karmic Koala. I can not use Ubuntu install of Diamondback because of the low version of my Operation System. So I check out the source code.
I learn from the beginner tutorial. But When I test to run roscore. It does not work well.
the error is listed;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/qli/ros/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
    from ros import roslaunch
  File "/home/qli/ros/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    return __import__(name)
  File "/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from roslaunch.scriptapi import ROSLaunch
  File "/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
    import roslaunch.parent
  File "/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/parent.py", line 55, in <module>
    import roslaunch.server
  File "/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/server.py", line 70, in <module>
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: No module named rosgraph_msgs.msg
```

I use the roswtf to check.
It said that:
ERROR: The ROS communication libraries have not been built. To fix:
rosmake ros_comm

When I build the ros_comm, the error is listed as follows.

```
  Linking CXX executable ../examples/example
  /home/qli/ros/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib/librostime.so: undefined reference to `boost::thread_resource_error::thread_resource_error()'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../examples/example] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/example.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qli/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/build'
```

I am a beginner of ros, so any comments and advice are welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10950/roscore-does-not-work-with-diamondback-on-karmic/) by [Qiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/969/qiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running Karmic you should run a supported version of ROS unless you have a very good reason.  [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) outlines the supported platforms and as you mentioned diamondback is not supported on Karmic.  This will mean that you will have many problems in terms of system dependencies and compatibility it obviously does not compile from your attempt.  And it is not expected to compile.  Especially if you're a beginner, I would suggest not trying to do unsupported things.

You have two options:

Either upgrade your OS to one on which diamondback is supported.  Or switch to use cturtle.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2